# How to gets gpio status but does not change it

Tags: gpio, libgpiod

use chardev gpiov2

```c
int get_gpio_status(const int gpio_offset) {

    int gfd = -1, lfd = -1, ret = 0, rc, offset = -1;
    struct gpio_v2_line_request req;
    struct gpio_v2_line_values value;
    char gpio_dev[20] = "/dev/gpiochip3";

    if (offset == -1)
        offset = gpio_offset;

    memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
    /* Configure input mode */
    req.config.flags = GPIO_V2_LINE_FLAG_INPUT;
    req.config.num_attrs = 0;

    /* open GPIO group device, get the fd */
    gfd = open(gpio_dev, O_WRONLY);
    if (gfd == -1) {
        ret = -errno;
        return ret;
    }

    /* line offset in requested GPIO group */
    req.offsets[0] = offset;
    /* just request one line */
    req.num_lines = 1;

    ret = ioctl(gfd, GPIO_V2_GET_LINE_IOCTL, &req);
    if (ret == -1) {
            goto __exit_gfd_close;
    } else {
        lfd = req.fd;
    }

    ret =  ioctl(lfd, GPIO_V2_LINE_GET_VALUES_IOCTL, &value);

    if (ret == -1) {
        goto __exit_gfd_close;
    }

    rc = (int)value.bits;


    // close
    if ((lfd > 2) && (close(lfd) == -1))
        perror("Failed to close lfd ");
    if ((gfd > 2) && close(gfd) == -1)
        perror("Failed to close gfd ");


__exit_gfd_close:
    if ((gfd > 2) && close(gfd) == -1)
        perror("Failed to close gfd");

__exit_lfd_close:
    if ((lfd > 2) && (close(lfd) == -1))
        perror("Failed to close lfd");
    
    return rc;
}
```

use libgpiod

gpiod examples: Request a line as input.

use GPIOD_LINE_DIRECTION_AS_IS   There is no change in the result

> gpiod_line_settings_set_direction(settings, GPIOD_LINE_DIRECTION_AS_IS);

```c
static struct gpiod_line_request *request_input_line(const char *chip_path,
                                                     unsigned int offset,
                                                     const char *consumer) {
    struct gpiod_request_config *req_cfg = NULL;
    struct gpiod_line_request *request = NULL;
    struct gpiod_line_settings *settings;
    struct gpiod_line_config *line_cfg;
    struct gpiod_chip *chip;
    int ret;
    chip = gpiod_chip_open(chip_path);
    if (!chip)
        return NULL;

    settings = gpiod_line_settings_new();
    if (!settings)
        goto close_chip;

    gpiod_line_settings_set_direction(settings, GPIOD_LINE_DIRECTION_INPUT);


    line_cfg = gpiod_line_config_new();
    if (!line_cfg)
        goto free_settings;

    ret = gpiod_line_config_add_line_settings(line_cfg, &offset, 1,
                                              settings);
    if (ret)
        goto free_line_config;

    if (consumer) {
        req_cfg = gpiod_request_config_new();
        if (!req_cfg)
            goto free_line_config;

        gpiod_request_config_set_consumer(req_cfg, consumer);
    }

    request = gpiod_chip_request_lines(chip, req_cfg, line_cfg);

    gpiod_request_config_free(req_cfg);

    free_line_config:
    gpiod_line_config_free(line_cfg);

    free_settings:
    gpiod_line_settings_free(settings);

    close_chip:
    gpiod_chip_close(chip);

    return request;
}



int read_gpio_status(const int gpio_chip, const int gpio_offset) {


    const char *chip_path = gpio_chip == 0 ? GPIO_CHIP_3 : GPIO_CHIP_5;


    struct gpiod_line_request *request;
    enum gpiod_line_value value;
    int ret;

    request = request_input_line(chip_path, gpio_offset, "get-line-value");
    if (!request) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to request line: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    value = gpiod_line_request_get_value(request, gpio_offset);

    *//* not strictly required here, but if the app wasn't exiting... *//*
    gpiod_line_request_release(request);


    return value;
}
```

I used the above two methods to obtain the status of gpio, and the result obtained is after modification.

I wonder if it’s because of iotcl

```c
from linux-5.10/include/uapi/linux/gpio.h

/*
 * v2 ioctl()s
 */
#define GPIO_V2_GET_LINEINFO_IOCTL _IOWR(0xB4, 0x05, struct gpio_v2_line_info)
#define GPIO_V2_GET_LINEINFO_WATCH_IOCTL _IOWR(0xB4, 0x06, struct gpio_v2_line_info)
#define GPIO_V2_GET_LINE_IOCTL _IOWR(0xB4, 0x07, struct gpio_v2_line_request)
#define GPIO_V2_LINE_SET_CONFIG_IOCTL _IOWR(0xB4, 0x0D, struct gpio_v2_line_config)
#define GPIO_V2_LINE_GET_VALUES_IOCTL _IOWR(0xB4, 0x0E, struct gpio_v2_line_values)
#define GPIO_V2_LINE_SET_VALUES_IOCTL _IOWR(0xB4, 0x0F, struct gpio_v2_line_values)
```

They are all _IOWR  Could this be the problem?

Comment: Who is the owner of the line? I.o.w. which process or driver requested that GPIO line first.

Comment: Btw, ` gpiod_line_settings_set_direction(settings, GPIOD_LINE_DIRECTION_INPUT);` This is **not** AS_IS.

Comment: @0andriy I've tried gpiod_line_settings_set_direction(settings, GPIOD_LINE_DIRECTION_AS_IS) which seems to have no effect

Comment: I sent an email to **linux-gpio@vger.kernel.org (the address on github, seems to be the author)** and he said that if my gpio is configured correctly and has not been changed externally, it will not change the electrical level

Comment: That is a mailing list, and you never replied or referenced this question making following up with you difficult.  I'm still not understanding your problem.  Your read_gpio_status() always returns low?  What is driving the line?  Are you sure you have the correct line?
Have you confirmed that the line is being driven externally? What does gpioinfo report for that line? What does gpioget report for that line?